# Center-stable manifold theorem on manifold with boundary

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, stability, hyperbolic-dynamics, topological-dynamics, gradient-flows

I would like to see if there is a Center-stable manifold theorem on the phase space that is a manifold with boundary. 
Suppose $f:M\rightarrow M$ is a diffeomorphism, according to Theorem III.7 in "Global stability of dynamical systems, M.Shub", at a fixed point $x^*\in M$, the tangent space $T_xM$ can be decomposed to $E^s\oplus E^c\oplus E^u$, based on that the norm of eigenvalues of $Df(x^*)$ are less than one, equal to one, greater than one). Then there is en embedded disc $W^{cs}$ tangent to $E^s$ at $x^*$ that is invariant under the iteration of $f$.

Question: Is there any results generalizing this theorem or giving counter example in the case when $M$ is a manifold with boundary?